# How do you print your programs to MS Word?

Tags: formatting, ms-word

We have a project, and the professor asked us to print the program codes using microsoft word. however when i pasted all my codes in ms word it turns out that it doesn't have coloring, those nice programming fonts.. It just looks awfully ugly in microsoft word..

I want this to be printed on papers very gorgeously. Like what we see in our notepad++

Comment: some sample input output will help.

Comment: There has not been a rational reason to print source code since the 80s.

Comment: Can't you print from Notepad++?

Comment: @Josh, he didn't say he wanted a hardcopy, per se...I think he just wants it in Word, but with the same formatting he has in notepad++...maybe it's for internal documentation or some such.

Comment: I find it interesting that useless questions like "What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?" get 500+ votes, while those related to programming, even if poorly worded, get downvoted...

Comment: its for my final exam grade. lol the prof wants it on microsoft word. so i need to follow his instruction..

Comment: @ruslan: thanks man. haha im not good at forging words. anyway i know what to do. gonna use visual studio.. you know because we use dev-c++/ its very archaic actually. but thats what we are using here. i can't do anything

Comment: Word is an excellent program for word processing.  It sucks as a program editor.  Not that I'm being helpful here, but I wanted to badmouth any professor who mixes Word and source code.

Comment: The practical reason for printing hard-copies of source code is that some people are more comfortable working that way. It's not my preference, but saying that it is not rational is kind of arrogant and ignores the fact that people work best differently than other people.

Comment: I use hard copies of code when I'm trying to understand somebody else's codebase, since in that context the quantity of reading far outstrips the quantity of writing, and reading the screen for hours on end is quite tiring as opposed to paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you can open the source code in Visual Studio (assuming it is C++, C# or VB), copy the code, and paste it to Word.

"Visual Studio" to "Word" does keep the formatting (color and fonts).

Comment: Same thing happen when I paste code into Outlook, the formatting is retained (since Outlook uses Word internally).

Answer (score 2):

I do not use Word for this when I can avoid it. It's simply not very good at keeping the formatting and doesn't provide really good-looking prints.

- The line-breaking isn't program-aware.
- The paragraph breaking isn't program aware.
- The keeping of the formatting from VS doesn't do structure-based markup, does it?
- The typesetting engine of Word is a lot worse than TeX or Quark/Indesign

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word is very handy for code reviews. Particularly if you don't want to splurge for one of the tools explicitly designed for peer code reviews.  Each reviewer can insert their comments and/or modify the code themselves right in the document.  If you keep track changes on then you can see what was changed and accept or reject the changes. During the review you only have to cycle through the comments and changes. When you are all done, you can simply copy and paste the final product back into the source file.  It beats having to take a list of comments, decipher them and then incorporate the requests yourself.

EDIT: We use Visual Studio. So Cut/Paste between the source and Microsoft Word works fine, except in the cases where the line length exceeds the page size.

Comment: I wouldn't know since I've never used SVN. Is that Subversion? If so, it seems like just a source code control system. How would it help with peer reviews? The benefit of using Word is that there is no learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the NppExport Plugin, go to

> Plugins -> NppExport -> (Then you can choose between "Export to RTF", "Copy RTF to Clipboard", or "Copy all formats to clipboard")

Then open it in Microsoft Word if you choose export to rtf, or paste it to Word if you choose copy to clipboard

Hope this helps

I tried it for my SQL assignment and it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you're asking "how do I put my source code into Word and make it look pretty like Notepad++," you'll want to do some research into automating Microsoft Word.

[Word automation using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx)
[OLE Automation using Word (Article)](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3700)
[Microsoft Word Automation Class](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c14519)

Comment: yea, my brain is gonna explode. but i upp'd it cause i wanna study it later. very resourceful

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious, but how about you just print it from notepad++?

Comment: He doesn't want a hard copy.  He needs it in MS Word.  I think he just used the "print" verb to describe a possible method of getting the formatting from Notepad++ to Word.

Comment: yes because we need to add additional details. and some screenshots of the running program.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does the same thing told by decasteljau.

When you copy code from eclipse, and then you paste on Outlook, the code keeps its colours.